# ng-grid-flexible-height.js 2.0.8 not re-sizing correctly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

In the following http://plnkr.co/edit/B7Y6WNmmw8Z2pfohFPjy?p=preview

It seems like virtualization is not being respected. I have the height set to 300px and set to only show 25 records at a time, but instead the grid is showing all available data at once.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!
Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ngGridFlexibleHeightPlugin`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/tree/master/plugins) ("Automatically resize a table to accomodate a varying number of rows.") you're including is overriding your settings.  It's adjusting the css directly on the element so it's changes are overriding yours.

So, the plugin overrides virtualization.  If you want to manually control the height of the grid remove this plugin from your options:

```
plugins: [new ngGridFlexibleHeightPlugin()]
```

If you want it to support a max-height (flexible height until it hits a max) then it looks like you'd need to add that to the plugin yourself.  [plugin code here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/plugins/ng-grid-flexible-height.js)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your last comment but note that you can easily make flexible height until it hits a max by using `max-height: 300px` instead of `height: 300px` in the plnkr above.

Answer (score 1):

Set the maxHeight option - e.g. ngGridFlexibleHeightPlugin({ maxHeight : 300}) will set the max height to 300..